# c++ error ‘const class std::vector<Nodo>’ has no member named ‘find’;

Tags: c++, array, iteradores, set

estoy usando una estructura de `set` que contiene un `vector`, que a  su vez contiene un objeto de una clase llamada `Nodo`, cuando trato de usar la función `find()` del vector de la `stl` me sale un error, considera que es una función de `Nodo` y que debería estar en esa clase.

He incluido todos los ficheros y librerías necesarias.
Código:

```
if((*lista_cerrada.end()).find((*lista_cerrada.end()).begin(),(*lista_cerrada.end()).end(),ns)==(*lista_cerrada.end()).end())
                (*lista_cerrada.end()).push_back(ns);
```

Error:

```
error: ‘const class std::vector<Nodo>’ has no member named ‘find’; did you mean ‘cend’?
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error lo tienes porque la clase `vector` **no tiene** ningún método `find`. Únicamente los contenedores ordenados tienen este método.

Para el resto de contenedores tienes a tu disposición el método `std::find` en la librería `algorithm`:

```
if( std::find(std::begin(vector),std::end(vector),ns) == std::end(vector) )
  vector.push_back(ns);
```

Por otro lado, mucho cuidado... `end()`, suele devolverte un **iterador no válido**. `end()` representa la primera posición que ya no pertenece a la colección... así pues la línea que comentas, de funcionar, te va a dar errores en tiempo de ejecución. `end()` solo se debe usar al comparar iteradores.